# Angular4 reference html element without using template variable

Tags: angular

Is there a way to reference self in html template in angular? I mean something like :

```
<p-calendar... (click)="self.someOtherMethod()"> ... </p-calendar>
```

At the moment I can do this like :

```
<p-calendar... (click)="test(v)" #v>...</p-calendar>

test(v){
v.someOtherMethod();
}
```

p-calendar is component from Primeng, but what I ask is general Angular stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this :

```
<p-calendar... (click)="self.someOtherMethod()" #self>...</p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

P-Calendar has an ngModel property. If I understand you correctly, this should be the way to go:

```
<p-calendar... [(ngModel)]="yourDateModel" (click)="someOtherMethod(yourDateModel)">
.... 
</p-calendar>
```

In your component, you need to declare the `yourDateModel` like so:

```
yourDateModel: Date;
```

**EDIT:** This is drifting off a bit, but here is how I implemented the date-range with two calendars: (Maybe I still don't understand correctly?)

**HTML**

```
<p-calendar placeholder="Date from..."
        [(ngModel)]="dateRange.from"
        [maxDate]="dateRange.to"></p-calendar>
<p-calendar placeholder="Date to..."
        [(ngModel)]="dateRange.to"
        [minDate]="dateRange.from"></p-calendar>
```

**COMPONENT**

```
dateRange: DateRange;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but no, it has nothing to do with ngModel. I just want to reference 'self' on any tag in template and it should work on any component . In your example someOtherMethod would be defined in component that uses p-calendar in its template, whereas I want to run method defined in p-calendar.

Comment: Ok I understand. Now in a component you've created your own: Why not just add the (click) to an element inside this component and define your method there?

Comment: Thats where primeng comes in. I wanted to invoke some method declared in their component, which was not visible like onClick. I can do it using template variable, but I don't want to pass it down.

Comment: Can you explain what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: I got 2 calendars (startDate,endDate) and they set max and min on the other. (I know there is range for that but I have to have 2 calendars) when you set endDate to yesterday and then on startDate click today button it allows to set start>end date which is a bug in my application. I needes to compensate that. I started with custom function onTodayClicked and needed to clear input - passed #self inside and made self.onClearButtonClick. It almost worked. I was curious is there a nicer way to run otherMethod from such component

Comment: Right now I changed it to run validation onInput where resigned from clearing the field and I only compare dates and disabling save button.

Comment: Yes, I have exactly that solution. Problem is that if you allow to use 'today' button user can select dateTo for tomorrow and then click today on dateFrom then it will bypass min/max and set incorrect values.